# Initialize ContentValue so it doesn't remain null?

Tags: java, android

I need a function to substitute from or add individual entries to a ContentValue. I haven't tested the nominal case yet but when bUpdatedFields is null, I get the error:

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.content.ContentValues.put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference"

```
public abstract class TableObject implements BaseColumns {

public TableObject() {
}

public ContentValues bUpdatedFields;

public ContentValues substituteBundleStringValue (ContentValues bundle, String key, String value){
        if (bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey(key)) bundle.remove(key);
        bundle.put(key, value);
        return bundle;
    }
```

The calling class (User) extends TableObject and, incidentally, the ContentValues which is sent as input of substituteBundleStringValue is bUpdatedFields, which is declared in TableObject.

Should I initialize bUpdatedFields? If so, how?

Calling method is:

```
public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
        bUpdatedFields = substituteBundleStringValue(bUpdatedFields, FIELD_NAME, name);
    }
```

Comment: show code where calling `substituteBundleStringValue` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle (of type ContentValues) value that you are passing to the method is null. The null check that you are doing for the bundle will only prevent the bundle.remove(key) statement from running if the bundle is null. From looking at your edited answer, it looks like you are passing bUpdatedFields and assigning it to the result of the same method.

But before you pass bUpdatedFields, you need to initialize it. In the line:

```
bUpdatedFields = substituteBundleStringValue(bUpdatedFields, FIELD_NAME, name);
```

bUpdatedFields is apparently null (and this is inferred from the error that you see). Have you initialized bUpdatedfields before you call the mentioned line of code? I mean, do you have a line somewhere that is:

```
bUpdatedFields = new ContentValues(); // initializing
```

My guess is, either you have not initialized this and you do not have the above line of code, or if you do have it, it's not being called before you call that line.

Comment: Actually, I want to substitute the current value if there is any. Otherwise, I DO want to put the new one. I added the null check because I didn't want the containsKey method to stumble upon a null bundle.

Comment: Ok.. have you initialized bUpdatedFields anywhere? Please see my edited answer and let me know if that answers your problem